# Getting page views by page category

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to create a report that tells me which location pages on my website get the most page views using Google Analytics. Basically everything under locations, I want the data from.

ex) sitename.com/locations/location-X.

location-1 ------ 20000 pageviews

location-2 ------ 30000 pageviews

location-3 ------ 40000 pageview

...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possible options:

1. Behaviour > Site Content > All Pages report and apply a regex filter for the page which contains `^\/locations\/location\-.*`
2. Behaviour > Site Content > Content Drilldown, click into the "locations" folder (and apply filter if necessary for `location\-.*`)

Comment: great, a follow up question would be how do I exclude urls with "?date=" at the end, which I am seeing a lot of and assuming they are generated from the site search.

Comment: You would need to adjust your regex to encompass or include the data parameter, so something like `location\-.*\?date=.*`